# Get max id for each entry from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables namely purchase and stock whose schema is as below:

entry:
Product:
product_Id
product_Name
product_Code

Purchase:
stock_Id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
product_Id Number
cost Number
rate Number

Stock:

stock_Id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY
product_Id
qty_left

Note: User is another table that I have.

For every row in entry table I can have multiple rows in the purchase table, where stock table actually holds product_Id.

Basically, entry is the stock table and a row is inserted in the purchase table every time a create or update occurs in the purchase table.

I need to have a query such that it returns the following columns: product_Id, product_Name, Cost and Rate from Purchase table and qty_left from stock table max(stock_Id) from stock table.

actually fetch max stock id from purchase table with relate to product id